# where can I find a prime forum for gtk+ (c++) type questions?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I am sorry if it defeats the purpose of this forum, but I see very limited GTK activity here and would like get heavily involved in it. What is the prime forum(s) where GTK is discussed. I use it primarily with c/c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.gtkforums.com? :-)
Or, better, use mailing lists:
http://www.gtk.org/development.html#MailingLists

Answer (score 1):

There are several hundred postings that appear when I [search for gtk+ using the Stack Overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gtk%2B)...just post your questions here.